# Bamboo script logs all output at the end. Bamboo thinks it hanged

Tags: continuous-integration, bamboo

Tried this on both windows and linux agents.  Create a script task that calls `python sleepandoutput.py` , which outputs and sleeps and outputs more.  Check the logs after the  plan finishes running, and theyre all at the same time.

The real problem is that when the duration is a long time, Bamboo kills the script.

How to get real time logs of processes that a script task creates?

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to call flush after writing.